# htaccess on ExpressionEngine MSM Site

Tags: expressionengine

I am running two ExpressionEngine sites on two different domain names using the MSM plugin. Site one has all the system files etc and site two is in a subfolder of site one. My question is how can I get site two to not have its index.php file in the url and still work?

Currently I have this in my htaccess folder of site one and site one works great, site two doesn't:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Removes index.php
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

    # Redirect non-www urls to www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If 404s, "No Input File" or every URL returns the same thing
    # make it /index.php?/$1 above (add the question mark)
```

Comment: Have you added the .htaccess file to site two as well? Assuming you have, in what way does it not work? E.g. is the homepage displayed for all requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same .htaccess should work for both sites. The rewriting only involves the index.php file, which is local to each site's root.

One possible issue I see from your .htaccess is that you're redirecting non-www URLs to www. Is your second domain setup to work with www? If not, this would obviously be a problem.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for this. I got it working with the same htaccess file in both site roots as you suggest and I am not sure why it started working (I had not changed anything). When you say: Is your second domain setup to work with www? Do you mean within the EE control panel general config settings?

Answer (score 1):

I use this htaccess file on both primary and secondary sites and all is good.

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm

AcceptPathInfo On

Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymLinks

# Looks for files and directories that do not exist
# and provide the segments to the index.php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^/index.php
RewriteCond $1 !.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for this Steve, do you bother redirecting non-www URLs to www or vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your `# Redirect non-www urls to www` rewrite **before** the `# Removes index.php` rewirte.

Having the www rewrite before the remove index.php rewrite has caused issues for me in the past and in a quick test of one of my sites, accessing the www-version when the www rewrite is placed before the remove index.php rewrite causes index.php not to be removed from the URL.

Comment: Thanks for this Alex I'll give that a try, I managed to get things working with the code as is, so I am not sure what I was doing wrong before. This is my first MSM site so I am still working my way through things.